# Tab bar items image doesn't appear after presentview

Tags: ios, swift

I coded my application with Swift 2. When i was trying to create my application, i used this code after user login successfully

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("home") as! UITabBarController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

vc is a UITabBarController which has 3 UIViewController. After TabBar appears only selected TabBar's item's image appears. All the other images appears after 10 seconds or if i touch any of them it appears. If I set TabBarController as an initial view images appears successfully.

I checked the RAM status and application uses 14.5 mb on iPhone 6 plus so i don't think happens because of memory leak.

I searched everywhere but i couldn't find any problem same as mine.

SOLVED:

I was using Touch ID in my code and this presentviewcontroller code was in completion. Raywenderlich handled completion with treads like this.

```
authContext.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "Testing Touch ID", reply: { (complete, error) -> Void in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                if complete {
                    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("home") as! UITabBarController
                    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

            else{

            }
            })

        })
```

I change my code like this and it worked fine. I edited my answer maybe this is a Xcode bug or else.

Comment: strange.  just tested it in my own project having many view controller - doesn't happen here. must be related to your project. would like to send me to check it in my computer?

Comment: can i get your github username so i can add you to project

Comment: I am an active github user but it is same with my stackoverflow user name. smozgur. I'd love to compile and run in my computer to let you know what happens as a second environment.

Comment: interesting - actually I can swear that I wrote "I am not an active github user".

Comment: Mert: It is working without problems. I can see all tab bar items at the bottom.

Comment: did you test it on simulator or on device?

Comment: :) of course both. Actually I was gonna ask if you'd also like me to test it in iPad but I can't see any reason.

Comment: Got your xCode updated? iDevice and xCode are talking same version? Just checking...

Comment: If you check my code you'll see that i'm using Touch Id, i tried it without touch id and it worked so i looked for answer little bit and found this solution: handling touch id completion with tread. It solved my problem. Thanks man for your help :)

Comment: ah, I forgot to mention that I skipped password and touch id steps nicely  since you said vc is opened and I tested in iPhone 5. perhaps that's the reason I didn't hit the wall. Glad to be able to help somehow :) Have a good night.

Comment: By the way, how it was solved exactly, after finding out it is related with touch id?

Comment: i edited my answer for other people, have a good night too